# send a large number of records from a rest service

Tags: php, xml, json, rest, download

I have a REST service in PHP, that returns me a JSON or XML response. But one branch of this service is for updating a local database and the problem is the number of records is more or less 180 000.

My question is, what is the best approach for this operation with a large number of records?

I thought of creating a temporary file on server like csv , txt for json or xml and downloading on client otherwise recursively send a GET request from a list of id of a previous request

possibile solution after read the comment

I find the solution in create a csv file (28MB) then zip (5MB) and passing that for downloading...

Comment: What is your concrete problem with the number of records? Do you get any error message? From what I know both JSON and XML don't have a limit for the number of elements you can encode. Both formats might be a little verbose, however, if you enable compression within the HTTP layer, it's mostly taken care about that.

Comment: the server return memory error and the time of exsecution of the procedure increseand when the data amount increasing

Answer (score 1):

A webservice that returns 180k records is conceptually wrong, and an accidental DoS attack waiting to happen (not to mention a closed hosting account because of traffic quota).

You should implement paging on this, like:

```
http://myserver.tld/myservice/getItems?from=100&max=1000
```

Cap the `max` parameter at a reasonable amount (1000 or perhaps 10000 for relatively small records), and be sure to expose a way of finding out the total number of rows - either in the result from this call or in another `getItemCount` call for example.

Comment: One standard in data-exchange that supports paging as well as batch processing (and REST btw.) is OData: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793748

Answer (score 0):

@Neils is right, your RESTful service should not be providing that many records in a single request.  Implement paging and add HAL (http://phlyrestfully.readthedocs.org/en/latest/halprimer.html) links if you choose.

If your client truthfully needs a full set of data that large (which again, probably is a design that needs revisiting) you're looking at a different use case.  Generate that data set asychronously and cache appropriately.  Also consider whether XML/JSON is the right format for a dataset that large, knowing that your client is going to have to load and parse it.  Can a flat CSV or something suffice?